# How should I inject Fused Location Provider Client into ViewModel in MVVM (With Compose and Dagger-Hilt)

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, dagger-hilt, fusedlocationproviderapi

**Context of the Problem**

I'm currently learning how to use the MVVM pattern with Compose and dependency injection with Dagger-Hilt.

I need to create a [FusedLocationProviderClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient) so I can update the location state of my GoogleMap Composable from my View Model.

**Considerations**

I believe that the FusedLocationProviderClient should be created from the Main Activity since it is an android-specific operation (and it requires an activity context). I also don't want to be passing my activity context to my view models because they cause memory leaks.

At the same time, since I am using Dagger-Hilt, I don't need to create my ViewModels in the Activity since they can easily be injected into my composable screens with:

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen(viewModel : MainViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {/*UI logic*/}
```

In my `MainActivity`, the only composable in `setContent{}` is a function that has the `NavHost` and the `NavGraphBuilder`:

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private lateinit var navController: NavHostController
    private lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    private var latitude = 0.0
    private var longitude = 0.0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

        setContent {
            MyTheme {
                navController = rememberAnimatedNavController()
                Navigation(navController)
            }
        }
    }
```

**Problem**

So, while following MVVM principles, how can I inject the `FusedLocationProviderClient` into my ViewModel if the ViewModel doesn't have to be created in the MainActivity?

Thanks!

Note: I'm also trying to avoid using AndroidViewModel to get context since it will be more difficult to unit test.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using hilt, you can provide the `FusedLocationProviderClient` via module like:

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class LocationModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideFusedLocationProviderClient(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context
    ): FusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
}
```

And then just inject the FusedLocationProviderClient in your view model that need to be used:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val locationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
) : ViewModel() {
...
}
```

As I see the LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient() just required Context parameter, not Activity so I think you can use the SingletonComponent for the module and @ApplicationContext for the context, but if it only requires the activity context, you can try to use the ActivityRetainedComponent for the module and @ActivityContext for the context, it will get the context of the activity for the getFusedLocationProviderClient() method